# Django - translate clause "WHERE identity IN (SELECT identity ... GROUP BY identity)" to django orm

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have such a schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/88c6a

It is simple variation on versioning model, where all versions of single entity have the same `identity`.
I have to find all records which used to have `category = 2` in their history.

How can I reproduce such query in Django? (Or any alternative queries)

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
WHERE identity IN (SELECT identity
                   FROM some_table
                   WHERE category = 2
                   GROUP BY identity
) AND is_latest = true;
```

I tried to retrieve these identities in application

```py
class SomeTableQueryset(QuerySet):
    def had_category_2(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("""
SELECT identity
FROM some_table
WHERE category = 2
GROUP BY identity;
            """)
        valid_identities = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

and filter queryset by

```py
        qs = qs.filter(identity__in=valid_identities)
```

But such approach has several cons:

1. it's not lazy, so query will be executed as soon as had_category_2 is
   called
2. it's very slow for obvious reasons

So, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
qs
.filter(
    identity__in=Subquery(
        qs
        .filter(category=2)
        .distinct('identity')
        .values('identity')
    )
)
```